# POST JSON with MVC 4 API Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have this code:

```
   $.ajax({


        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/slide",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"Title":"fghfdhgfdgfd"}',
        dataType: "json",
```

An this is my controler:

```
public class SlideController : ApiController
{

    // POST /api/Slide
    public void Post(string Title)
    {
    }
```

When I run the code and call the /api/Slide, the [Title] has no data and is null.

How do I post JSON to the API controller?

```
POST http://127.0.0.2:81/api/slide HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.2:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Origin: http://127.0.0.2:81
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://127.0.0.2:81/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Title=fghfdhgfdgfd
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define a view model:

```
public class SlideViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
public class SlideController : ApiController
{
    // POST /api/Slide
    public void Post(SlideViewModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

finally invoke the action:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/slide',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }),
    success: function() {
        ...    
    }
});
```

The reason for that is that simple types such as strings are bound from the URI. I also invite you to read the [following article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) about model binding in the Web API.

Comment: I can't understand how it knows which action we are trying to call? In this controller we can have hundreds of them.

Comment: It's RESTful and conventional. You are using POST verb in your jQuery request => the Post action is invoked. If you used the `GET` verb (for example typing the action name directly in your browser address bar) => the Get action would have been invoked. So you cannot have hundreds of them. The standard HTTP verbs are `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` so those are the action names you should be using. Of course you could always violate the standard RESTful conventions => go ahead and modify the routes in your `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` file so that you include the action name in the url.

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between  data: JSON.stringify({ title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }), and  data: '{Title:"fghfdhgfdgfd"}', that I ended up using?

Comment: Of course that there's a difference. The `JSON.stringify` method generates a JSON encoded string of the javascript variable you are sending. Whereas if you use simply `{ title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }` then jQuery is no longer sending a JSON encoded string at all. It is using an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, thta's why you should remove the `contentType: 'application/json'` setting in this case.

Comment: OK, but I can format the json myself, right? Like this - data: '{"Title":"fghfdhgfdgfd"}'.

Comment: Primitive data types are not supported in the body of the POST request. You will have to write a custom media formatter if you want this to work or decorate the action parameter with the `[FromBody]` attribute and then send the request like this on the client: `data: '=' + encodeURIComponent('fghfdhgfdgfd'),`. Did you read the article  I have linked to in my answer about model binding in the web API?

Comment: Looks like there some confusion here. I am using data: '{"Title":"fghfdhgfdgfd"}' and it works like a charm with the view model. Are you saying that this should not work or is there some other problem?

Comment: Yes, it works with a view model, that's what I suggested you using in my answer. It doesn't work with a controller action taking a primitive type: `public void Post(string title) { ... }`.

Answer (score 10):

Ensure the object you are trying to convert to has a default (empty) constructor.

Rule of thumb: If you want to deserialize to an object, you need to make it simple for the objects to be created. These guidelines can help:

- All properties that are to be passed around **must be public**
- the object needs to able to be **constructed without any parameters**.

This JSON string/object for example:

```
{ Name: "John Doe", Phone: "123-456-7890", Pets: [ "dog", "cat", "snake" ] }
```

can be converted to an object from the following class:

```
 public class Person {

     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Phone { get; set; }
     public string[] Pets { get; set; }

  }
```

or this one:

```
public class Person {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string[] Pets { get; set; }
   public Person() {}
   public Person(string name, string phone) {
      Name = name;
      Phone = phone;
   }

}
```

or this one:

```
public class Person {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string[] Pets { get; set; }
    public Person() {}


 }
```

but not this one

```
public class Person {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string[] Pets { get; set; }
    public Person(string name, string phone) {
      Name = name;
      Phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Now let ASP.NET MVC 4 do the rest

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
        // .. other actions 
        public HttpResponseMessage PostPerson(Person person)
        {
            if ( null != person)
                // CELEBRATE by doing something with your object
            else 
                // BE SAD and throw and exception or pass an error message

        }
        // .. other actions 
}
```

If your class cannot have a default constructor or if you don't have access to the source code for the class, you can create an adapter class that

- has a default constructor
- exposes those properties that need to be public

Using the Person class above with no default constructor, an adapter could look like

```
public class PersonAdapter {

    public Person personAdaptee;

    public string Name {
        get { return personAdaptee.Name; }
        set { personAdaptee.Name = value }
    }

    public string Phone {
        get { return personModel.Phone; }
        set { personModel.Phone = value; }
    }

    public string[] Pets {
        get { return personAdaptee.Pets; }
        set {personAdaptee.Pets = value }
    }

    public PersonAdapter() {

        personAdaptee = new Person("", "", null);

    }

}
```

Now let ASP.NET MVC 4 do the rest

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
        // .. other actions 
        public HttpResponseMessage PostPerson(PersonAdapter person)
        {
            if ( null != person)
                // CELEBRATE by doing something with your object
            else 
                // BE SAD and throw and exception or pass an error message

        }
        // .. other actions 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/slide",
    data: { Title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }
});
```

It is the quotes around the data attribute which are causing this:

i.e  >>   data: { Title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" } 
not  >>   data: **'**{ Title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }**'**

UPDATE:
Also your controller seems a little strange, although it is hard to tell without seeing your routing, etc.

I would expect to see something more like this:

```
public class SlideController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage PostSlide(string Title)
    {
        // Do your insert slide stuff here....

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Clearly, you will also need to update the URL in your jQuery too.

Take a look here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

ANOTHER UPDATE:

It would be usual to create a CLR object to match your Json and use the MVC model binder to bind directly to that. If you don't want to do that you can bind to an object and deserialize into a Dictionary:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post(object json)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json.ToString());
    var x = values["Title"];
}
```

Comment: the change did not help, I still get null when I breakpoint in the controller.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MVC 4 API Controller? I am using the default MVC 4 API Controller scaffolding, with the empty methods.

Comment: Have you had a look at the HTTP headers with Fiddler to check what is being posted?

Comment: This is no longer supported in the RTM. You will have to write a custom media formatter if you want to bind primitive types (such as string) from the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the action parameter to FromBody i.e:

```
public class SlideController : ApiController
{

    // POST /api/Slide
    public void Post([FromBody]string Title)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/slide',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }),
    success: function() {
        ...    
    }
});
```

Controller is

```
public class SlideController : ApiController
{

    // POST /api/Slide
    public void Post(string Title)
    {
    }
```

Your url is not valid, url must address the action **Post** in **Slide** controller

edit your  url to url:"`~/ControllerName/ActionName`" in this context must be `Url:"~/Slide/Post"`