# Posting and receiving json with MVC Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have seen similar case to mine answered but I have specific need that always differed from others problem.

I am sending json data from my html page to the MVC Web API. Unfortunately the data I am receiving is ALWAYS null (I have tried a lot of different things here). The thing is I really need to received the data as json (string), because my data is very complex and cannot be simply deserialized by the Web API (I have my own custom deserializer that does it).

Heres the code!

First, the web api controller that will receive the ajax post request

```
public class ActivityController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/activity
    public string Post([FromBody]string json)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, the ajax request itself

```
$.ajax("/api/activity", {
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { json: ko.mapping.toJSON(fusionedModel) },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

As far as the data is concerned, it is rendered well (I've used that same request with MVC (not Web Api) and the server was receiving the string perfectly... now for some reason, in my web api controller, the "json" param is ALWAYS null. **As I said before, it is IMPORTANT that I receive the data as a json string.**

**EDIT : I found that my question is a duplicate of this one : [POST JSON with MVC 4 API Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446024/post-json-with-mvc-4-api-controler)
But I really don't like the answer... having to create an object just to encapsulate the string is very dirty...**

Comment: I always get this issue when I use invalid JSON (it's very strict, try opening the JSON file in Visual Studio, it sometimes shows issues that aren't shown in other online JSON validators).
I'm currently getting the issue with what seems to be valid JSON though. Have you tried submitting very basic JSON like {} ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you avoid using standard body parameter binding as that mechanism assumes that you are trying to deserialize the body into a CLR object.  Try this,

```
public class ActivityController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/activity
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
         var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         return new HttpResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

If you really want to use parameter binding, you can do this.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(JToken jToken)
    {

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(jToken.ToString())
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'm new to the Web Api, but this seams very interesting! Is there any good article on this (the use of async with HttpRequestMessage) that you would recommend? Btw, for some reason, the json it is receiving with the "ReadAsStringAsync" is full of character like "%22%3A%5B%7B%22" instead of normal "{" and "[" so I can't do anything with it.

Comment: @zwk It looks like your JSON is being URI encoded. Can you show that code?

Comment: @zwk What is it that you are looking for regarding async action methods?  There are underlying details here http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch12.html#_controller_activation

Comment: I'm not sure what other part of the code you would like to see, but as for the Http header of the ajax request, the data is correctly encoded. As for the controller, I'm doing exactly what you suggest.

Comment: One thing I REALLY don't understand though, is that receiving JSON should be trivial...

Comment: Actually, you're right... now the http header contains the wrongly formatted json... that is very weird as nothing was changed in the javascript...

Comment: @zwik  Receiving any type of content is trivial once you understand how the HttpContent class works and give up on the model binding junk.  Unfortunately everybody thinks they want to send objects over the wire.

Comment: Again, as soon as I am using the async with the HttpRequestMessage as param, the json gets formatted as said before... If I don't use this, it is formatted correctly. See my edit, I found a solution, but I really don't like it...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the  [HttpPost] Attribute that can be located on System.Web.Http;

```
public class ActivityController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/activity
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string json)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before. Unfortunately it didn't change a thing. As far as the way Web API works, it shouldn't have changed a thing, but I tried it anyway, without success...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but it looks like you haven't included your action in the post URL. Try changing

```
$.ajax("/api/activity", {
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { json: ko.mapping.toJSON(fusionedModel) },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

To

```
$.ajax("/api/activity/POST", {
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { json: ko.mapping.toJSON(fusionedModel) },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. The way the MVC Web API works is that by doing an ajax request with type POST, you are reaching for the post method of the controller. In any case, my problem is not that it can't reach the method, its that the param is null.