# Posting JSON in MCV4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have seen solution on [Posting and receiving json with MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967349/posting-and-receiving-json-with-mvc-web-api)
to pass JSON parameter using APIController.

I want to do the same, but I have Visual Studio 2010, MCV4, framework 4.0, and the above isn't correct code for my versions.
async returns syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major problem is that "JSON" had been thought mistakenly as simple string.
All needed is to pass json and return json.

"POST" shall be written like follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JToken value)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, value.ToString(), "application/json");
}
```

Things work fine. The little difference is JToken.

"GET" shall be written like follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var res = "";
    JToken j;
    res = "some json string";
    j = JToken.Parse(res);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, j, "application/json");
}
```

Thanks, anyway :)