# Send JSON using Ajax in Querystring along with regular params

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Is it possible to include a simple JSON string at the end of a querystring using Ajax GET? I'm using MVC and sending from the View to the Controller. In the Controller I want to be able to do this:

```
public class myObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetData(string Id)
{
    // Get querystring parameter
    string a = Request["a"];

    // Create typed object
    if (Request["myObj"] != null)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        myObj myobj = null;
        myobj = jss.Deserialize<myObj>(Request["myObj"]);
    }

    ...
}
```

In the View:

```
var myObj = '{ "Name" : "John", "Age" : "22" }';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/GetData/?Id=" + $("#Id").val(),
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        a: $('#a').val(),
        myObj: myObj
    },

    ...

});
```

I don't think my example above illustrates why I want to do this, but my question is whether or not this is possible. When the Ajax GET is executed `myObj` is always null in the Controller. I suspect it's because `data:` is creating a JSON already and myObj is not in the correct format, but I don't know how to fix this and can't seem to find an example showing how.

If this combination is possible can someone point me to where my code is wrong?

Comment: I would be careful when using query string to pass data. Try using POST instead, and you will not have to worry about query string limitations

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to use POST without the View reloading, so I settled in to using GET.

Comment: you could easily change the attribut in the answer that you got to be POST, then do the exact same thing.  The difference is the size of the request can be much larger in a POST

Comment: Your view shouldn't reload if you make an asynchronous call, even if it is using POST. How did you implement the function? http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

Comment: Daniel, I'm VERY interested in your input on making this a POST instead of GET. I don't like the messy querystring params in the URL. I'm not sure which function implementation you are asking about. It just seemed that each time a POST was issued the View's associated controller action was being called. I see you provided a link. I'm going to go read it now. I would much rather be issuing a POST...

Comment: It appears that the only different between my Ajax GET and an Ajax POST is the `type: "POST"`. I'm going to revisit this approach. It just seemed that every way I tried to POST my view was getting reloaded and that's not going to work for this application.

Comment: Change the type to POST as you suggested, and don't forget to update your Action to accept POST requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the amount of data you want to pass over (12 params) with potentially a lot of data, you may want to use POST rather than GET.

[Examples of AJAX POST](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/)

```
var myObj= { "Name" : "John", "Age" : "22" }; //Array with similar properties to your Model

$.ajax({
    url : "/GetData/", 
    type: "POST",
    data : myObj,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

and ensure that your Action is accepting the HTTP POST verb.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult GetData(string id, string a, myObj myObj)
{
}
```

See [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446024/post-json-with-mvc-4-api-controler) for additional info.

Comment: Daniel, I spent a considerable amount of time trying to get POST to work without having the View reload. I gave up on it and went with GET. I tried it again and it seems to work fine - change `type: POST` in Ajax and decorate the Controller function with `HttpVerbs.Post`. I don't know why it didn't work before, but thank you for nudging me to try it again. It's a much better solution.