# How to send POST with multiple parameters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

EDIT: I've updated the web service as shown below. Now I can send a JSON object and get the expected result, using Postman (the web service sends me an email successfully).

I'm brand new to Angular, and the web service I'm hitting is the first I ever wrote, and I need help with sending the POST to the web service.

Here is the signature for the ASP.NET Web API that I'm sending to, and it works properly when I send the POST using Postman (UPDATED):

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool Post(Email msg)
    {
        return SendEmailMessage(msg);
    }
```

Here's my controller in AngularJS (UPDATED with vm.msg):

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('About', ['dataService', About]);

function About(dataService) {
    var vm = this;
    //(bunch of stuff removed for brevity)      
    vm.sendMail = function (form) {
        vm.submitted = true;
        vm.mailResult = dataService.sendMail.send(vm.msg);
        if (vm.mailResult) {
            vm.cancel();
        };
    };
    return vm;
}
})();
```

Here's my service in AngularJS:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('dataService', ['$resource', dataService]);

function dataService($resource) {
    return {
        sendMail: sendMail
    };

    function sendMail(msg) {
        return $resource('/api/email/:data',
            {},
            {
                send: { method: 'POST', params: { data: msg} }
            });
    };
};})();
```

Here's the POST that I'm sending with Postman, which works:

> mywebservice.com/api/email POST with a JSON object sends successfully with Postman to the webservice, and returns the expected result (the webservice sends me an email).

Somehow, I know that my service is screwed up, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I've looked at documentation, and examples, but they all have you using a factory, and I am trying to do this using the iife method (again, I'm new at this). Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!
Rich

Comment: Why are you using `$resource`? It would be simpler to just use the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Also it would be simpler to have the form fill in a message object instead of splitting it into three model variables.

Comment: I'm using $resource because several things I read suggested it was easier. If not, how? Also, I tried sending an object, and couldn't figure out how to receive it in the service, so I went back to individual parameters. If there is an easier way, please post it as an answer - I appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

The web service is as edited above, allowing the JSON object to be sent to it. The code in the controller is as follows:

```
vm.sendMail = function (form) {
        vm.submitted = true;
        vm.msg.message = vm.msg.message.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\n\r)/gm, '<br/>');

        var sendMessage = new emailService();
        sendMessage.$save(vm.msg)
            .then(function () {
                vm.sendSuccess = true;
                vm.sendFailed = false;
                vm.cancel();
            })
            .catch(function() {
                vm.sendSuccess = false;
                vm.sendFailed = true;
                vm.submitted = false;
            });
    };
```

The code in the service is as follows:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('emailService', ['$resource', emailService]);

function emailService($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/email');
};
})();
```

Thanks for the help, but I really wanted to learn how to do this with the $resource that I'd started out with.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that coders first get the API working with the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) before packaging it into a factory or using a REST api library such as [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource#ngresource).

To post to an API that receives the data in URL parameters:

```
    var config = { params: vm.msg };
    $http.post(url, vm.msg, config)
      .then (function (response) {
        vm.result = "SUCCESS";
        vm.data = response.data;
        console.log(vm.data);
    }).catch(function (error){
        vm.result = "ERROR: "+error.status;
        console.log(error);
    })
```

The above example posts the data both in the POST body and as URL parameters. The form fills in a message object instead of splitting it into three model variables.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tmvwgwu90q5jieSfAVSh?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http){
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.msg = {
    name: "J. Doe",
    email: "j@doe.com",
    message: "Hi there"
  };
  var url = "//httpbin.org/post";
  
  vm.submit = function() {
    var config = { params: vm.msg };
    $http.post(url, vm.msg, config)
      .then (function (response) {
        vm.result = "SUCCESS";
        vm.data = response.data;
        console.log(vm.data);
    }).catch(function (error){
        vm.result = "ERROR: "+error.status;
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      Name&nbsp;<input ng-model="msg.name" />
      <br>Email&nbsp;<input ng-model="msg.email" />
      <br>Message
      <br><textarea ng-model="msg.message">
          </textarea>
      <br><button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <p>{{result}}</p>
    <p>{{data.url | json}}</p>
    <p>{{data.json | json}}</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Ok... I think I see what is going on here, but I don't see how to make my web service accept an object instead of the three parameters. I've tried creating a method in the controller that takes an object, tried taking a Email (the model that is used in the web service), but I only get an error. How is a javascript object to be converted to a .Net object?

Comment: That is another question. Look at [POST JSON with MVC 4 API Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539610/5535245).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send parameters as a query string so you don't need to declare parameter's name.

```
return $resource('/api/email',{},
        {
            send: { method: 'POST'}
        });
```

But if you want to send parameter as a rest template so you should declare parameters name.

```
 return $resource('/api/email/:name/:address/:message',{},
        {
            send: { method: 'POST', params:{name:@name,address:@address,message:@message} }
        });
```

and call the service like to this in controller

```
 dataService.sendMail.send({name:vm.name, email:vm.email, message:vm.message});
```

Comment: Where does the @ sign come in? I have seen it in other code samples I've looked at, but haven't seen an explanation of what it is for.

Comment: When I substitute my parameter names that are passed in, for your @ notation, I get a "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'send'. When I do everything as you typed it, I get an invalid character at dataService.js (19, 45) - the comma after @name, and $injector:modulerr, failed to initiate module app due to unknown provider dataServiceProvider. Also, all of the @ signs are underlined by the ide (VS2017 with ReSharper).

Comment: please see anhular API for `$resource` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: @RichHopkins Did you saw [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks.

Comment: So as you see in angularjs documents it's correct completely. now i don't know why you down voted my answer?

Comment: I didn't. Someone else did. I just added an upvote for you.